# How to direct initialize a C++ variant with one of its non-default option?

Tags: c++, initialization, variant

Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
    [...]
public:
    Foo(int);
}

class Bar {
    [...]
public:
    Bar(int);
}

using MyVariant = std::variant<Foo,Bar>;
```

How can one direct initialize (i.e no copy and no `Foo` building involved) an instance of `MyVariant` as a `Bar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the a tag of type [`std::in_place_type_t<Bar>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) as first constructor parameter:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo(" << value << ")\n";
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    Bar(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    Bar(Bar const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar(Bar const&)\n";
    }
    Bar& operator=(Bar const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar& operator=(Bar const&)\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::variant<Foo, Bar> var(std::in_place_type_t<Bar>{}, 1);
}
```

`std::in_place_index_t` would be an alternative first parameter, if you prefer passing the position of the type in the template parameter list of `std::variant`.